# Manage groups in different page with sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

i'm using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin, but i would like a little change, i have 2 groups(admins,users) and i want to manage them separately, what i mean is a page that only shows me the "admins" group and another one the "users" group, i want this because users in "users" group will have some additional info and behavior, i already create a "sfGuardUser" empty module in my backend app, so i can overwrite and add everything i want, i create de actions.class.php

```
class sfGuardUserActions extends autoSfGuardUserActions
{
    public function executeAdmins(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        // sorting
        if ($request->getParameter('sort') && $this->isValidSortColumn($request->getParameter('sort')))
        {
            $this->setSort(array($request->getParameter('sort'), $request->getParameter('sort_type')));
        }

        // pager
        if ($request->getParameter('page'))
        {
            $this->setPage($request->getParameter('page'));
        }

        $this->pager = $this->getPager();
        $this->sort = $this->getSort();
    }
}
```

i copied exactly the "executeIndex" function from "autoSfGuardUserActions" class in cache, and now i can go to guard/admin and it acts like the default one, but now, how can i show only de users from "admins" group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify `buildQuery()` method.

Comment: ok, but how i can identify the groups, sometimes i want to show one group, sometime the other one

Comment: `getPager()` calls `buildQuery()`, so you can pass object to `getPager()` in `executeIndex()`